# Good books on electromagnetism for nonlinear optics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, non-linear-optics

While reading books on nonlinear optics, I often come across concepts such as second-order susceptibility which is not covered in undergraduate E&M books like Griffiths. Are there any good E&M books that will cover such topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go wrong with Jackson's **Classical electrodynamics**. It's a classic, and it contains a broad variety of topics, even very advanced ones. It's a pretty mathematically heavy book, so before tackling it you should have a good understanding of complex, as well as real analysis. You can see the table of contents [here](https://www.wiley.com/en-it/Classical+Electrodynamics,+3rd+Edition-p-9780471309321).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any book that you would recommend for real and/or complex analysis?

Comment: Not a specific one, there are so many. I'm sure you'll find many references online, even on the mathematics stackexchange. See what fits you best.